# Spotfire - personalized information link

Tags: spotfire

I am creating personalised information link based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puc9gjv8_VI&feature=youtu.be

I am joining table with all data and Lookup table with usernames in Information Designer based on one column that is common for both.

But when I include filter and condition on my "User name" column to be 1% = (%CURRENT_USER%), I get nothing in data.

At the end you can find pictures with filter I use and my user name.

What can be potentially wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Picture 1:Filter in Information Designer

Picture 2:My user name in Spotfire

Picture 3:User name I have in my Lookup table

[image: Filter in Information Designer]

[image: My user name in Spotfire]

[image: User name I have in my Lookup table]

Comment: what database are you using? MSSQL?